# No Matching record is found IN MongoDB Stitch app webhook function

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-stitch

I have a MongoDb ATLAS database as "**BOULDERS_MAIN**" and a collection inside it "**users**", I am writing a webhook function for returning a user based on email i.e. "**kb**", but all I'm getting is empty object.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB's `find()` returns a cursor object not the results. Try calling [toArray()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/) on the result instead:

```
var doc = users.find({email: 'kb'}).toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks @dnickless, additionally we can use : var doc = users.findOne({email: 'kb'});

Comment: @kushal: Yes, totally, if you only want to get one item. The `email: 'kb'` filter seemed to imply that there might be more matches...